# Check if char* is a number for numbers below 0

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a function which returns `true` when `char*` is a number and `false` when it isn't.

This is the code:

```
int isNumber(char* s) {
    if (*s == '\0') return 0;
    while (*s) {
        if (!isdigit(*s)) return 0;
        s++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

But what happens when I put, for example, "-5"? It's a number but the function returns `false`. How should I modify this function?

Comment: `'-'` is not a number.  Check for leading `'+'` or `'-'`.

Comment: Add the line before the while loop: `if (*s == '-') s++;`

Comment: You should also do what you did with the empty string: there must be a digit following `-` or `+`.

Comment: Add a new first line: `if (*s == '-' || *s == '+' ) { s++; } `

Comment: Come on, this is trivial, you should be able to find out yourself. If somewone gives you a piece of paper containing these words: `123`, `-123`, `+123`, `12a` and `ab12` how would _you_ tell if each of the words is a number or not?

Comment: what about `"5z"`? is it a number or not for ya?

Comment: ... and mind cases like this: `12+23` and `12-33`.

Comment: ...which has been dealt with by the suggested new first line, which is the only change needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work for whole numbers only.

It fails in cases where the number contains a sign or a decimal point.

If the number contains a sign then it must be the first character in the string. So before entering the while loop, check if the first character in the string is a '+' or '-' and ignore it inside the while loop if so.

```
if (*s == '+' || *s == '-') ++s;
```

To extend the code for numbers containing a decimal point, add a flag which restricts the occurrence of a '.' to only once in the string.

```
int decimalPointFound = 0; // Decimal point not found yet
```

And add the following code in the beginning of your while loop which handles the decimal point before checking if the character is a digit

```
if (*s == '.')

{

    if (decimalPointFound) return 0; // Invalid number if there are more than one '.'

    decimalPointFound = 1; // Update the flag since you have found a '.'

}
```

I hope this provides some flexibility to your function. There are still many cases to consider such as leading whitespaces, trailing whitespaces, exponential notation, complex numbers, etc. Depending on the domain of your numbers, modify this basic template of code.

By the way, you may be interested to look into some built-in [functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/atol-atoll-and-atof-functions-in-c-c/) which achieve your task.

Comment: When writing about parsing text for numbers, you should distinguish numbers (mathematical entities) from numerals (symbols, such as text, representing a number). For example, it is not true that the code will work for whole numbers only. “14.0” represents a whole number, yet the code will reject it. The phrase “the number contains a sign or a decimal point” is bad because numbers are abstract entities; they do not contain decimal points. Text (a sequence of characters) contains decimal points.